# ngModelChange triggering issues

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a website made with Angular. I have a page with a dropdown, using a (ngModelChange), that fills another dropdown with data depending on what is selected in the first dropdown. If nothing is selected, it fills the dropdown with all data.

I have a reste button, which delete the content of arrays "selected items" used by those dropdown (in order to reset them and make them with nothing selected).

I need a method that would do this in this order :

- Reset selected items
- Insert something in dropdown 2

The problem is, the code is executed, and this something is correctly put in the the dropdown BUT the DOM seems rendered after that, and the reset selected items trigger it's (ngModelChange) and so wrong things are put in my dropdown.

How can I avoid that ?

Here is some code :

HTML

```
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="linkedCpt">(Search by Competence)</label>
                    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
                    [placeholder]="'Select a Competence'"
                    [data]="dropdownCompetencesList"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedCompetencesItems"
                    [settings]="dropdownCompetencesSettings"
                    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (ngModelChange)="fillTypeFormationDropdown($event)"
                    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                    name="idCpt"
                    >
                    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="linkedCpt">Type Formation</label>
                    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
                    [placeholder]="'Select a type formation'"
                    [data]="dropdownTypesFormationList"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedTypesFormationItems"
                    [settings]="dropdownTypesFormationSettings"
                    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                    name="idTypeFormation"
                    >
                    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
                </div>
```

TS

```
fillTypeFormationDropdown(item: any){

this.dropdownTypesFormationList = [];
this.selectedTypesFormationItems = [];

if (this.selectedCompetencesItems && this.selectedCompetencesItems.length > 0){
  this.serviceFormationRequise.getAllByCompetence("GetByCompetence", this.selectedCompetencesItems[0]['idCpt'])
  .subscribe(response =>  {
      this.sharedSnackBarMessage.changeMessage("TypesFormation sucessfully received");
      this.snackBarService.openSuccessSnackBar(SnackbarMessageComponent);

      this.typeFormationCompetences = response as any;
      //Filling multiselect dropdown
      let dropdown = [];
      this.typeFormationCompetences.forEach(element => {          
        dropdown.push({idTypeFormation: element.idTypeFormation, nomTypeFormation: element.nomTypeFormation });
      }); 
      this.dropdownTypesFormationList = dropdown;
  });
} else {
  if (this.TYPEFORMATION_DATA && this.TYPEFORMATION_DATA.length){
  let dropdown = [];
  this.TYPEFORMATION_DATA.forEach(element => {          
    dropdown.push({idTypeFormation: element.idTypeFormation, nomTypeFormation: element.nomTypeFormation });
  }); 
  this.dropdownTypesFormationList = dropdown;
  }
}
}

resetForm(){
 this.selectedCompetencesItems = [];
 this.selectedTypesFormationItems = [];
}
```

New Method

```
newMethod(input: any){
 this.resetForm();
 this.selectedTypesFormationItems.push({idTypeFormation: input.idTypeFormation, nomTypeFormation: input.nomTypeFormation });
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you already have, and I'm sure more peeps would be happy to help.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a stackblitz example. We need more info in your question to fully understand the problem.

Comment: I added some code :).

Comment: As you can see, my problem is I ask to reset dropdown, then i put data in a dropdown, then (and i don't want to), onNgChange triggers at that time because of the reset and erase what i put to add other data.